# PWM on 16f error

Tags: c, embedded, pic, mplab, pwm

My code will not compile because of this error in this function can anyone help

```
void SetDCPWM(unsigned int dutycycle) {

unsigned int local_dutycycle;
local_dutycycle = dutycycle;

CCPR1L = (dutycycle >>2);

CCP1CONbits.DC1B = local_dutycycle & 0x0003;

return; }
```

I am getting this error

```
Error   [255] C:\KEVIN-WORK\WORK\SM511602\SM511601 TEK572A Syspeo RS232 receiver.c; 352.18 not a member of the struct/union ""

Error   [182] C:\KEVIN-WORK\WORK\SM511602\SM511601 TEK572A Syspeo RS232 receiver.c; 352.44 illegal conversion between types
unsigned int -> volatile union S30
```

Comment: yes I included the error messages in the post. I have tried but cannot find a fix

Comment: DC1B is apparently not a member of CCP1CONbits. Make sure both of those exist and that you include the header file where they are declared.

Comment: Since `CCPR1L` and `CCP1CONbits` look like macros, you can run your compiler to preprocess only. On GCC, this the `-E` option.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Is this MPLAB?

Comment: this seems to be the problem line: CCP1CONbits.DC1B = local_dutycycle & 0x0003;  it would have been very nice if you had added a comment indicating this is the problem line.  What is the definition of CP1CONbits?

Comment: I guess that the CCP1CONbits.DC1B register is an 8 bits register (pic16f are 8 bits architecture). And you are trying to put 16 bits in it (0x0003 is a 16 bits field). That could be the origin of the 2nd error (352.44 illegal conversion between types).